# Using Bash to run 2 python scripts at the same time

Tags: bash, multitasking

I want to run two Python Scripts at the same time. I found that using Bash you can do that. So i wrote the next code

`#! /usr/bin/env bash
import camera_centroid
import testsss
python camera_centroid.py &
python testsss.py &`

When i run it i get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have mixed between python and bash,
you don't need the import in the bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python camera_centroid.py &
python testsss.py &
wait # wait for jobs to be done
```

make sure you adding execute permissions to the scripts

```
chmod +x testsss.py camera_centroid.py
```

and finally run the script ./your_file.sh

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
import foo
```

in a shell script,  you are not importing the python module, instead, you are calling the `$(which import)` command/alias/function.

For example, if you have ImageMgick installed, very likely, you are making screenshot for window(s).

If you want to import python module, those `import foo` should be in your python files.

Comment: Conversely, you need to provide a specific path to `camera_centroid.py` and `testsss.py` as the arguments to the `python` command; `bash` has no way of locating them implicitly.